# PyQt: Pop previous commands from UndoStack during current command's undo

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm in a situation in which I have several commands of the same class pushed onto a `QUndoStack` and depending on user input another command of a different class might be pushed on top of those. What I would now like to achieve is to remove a fixed number of these previous commands of the first type from the undo stack (either by undoing them or just removing them, doesn't matter in my case) when the topmost command's `undo` is executed. E.g. like this:

```
class CommandA(QUndoCommand):
    # ...

class CommandB(QUndoCommand):
    def undo(self):
        # ...
        # somehow remove last N commands of class A from undostack

stack = QUndoStack()

stack.push(CommandA())
# ...
stack.push(CommandA())

stack.push(CommandB())
```

Just removing the last N commands regardless of which class they belong to would also be helpful as a starting point. This seems to me like it would be a common requirement but I don't see if/how this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

In `PyQt5`, commands on the `QUndoStack` are stored by index and accessed via the `command` function. You can loop over the commands in the stack using the `count` method:

```py
for ndx in range(stack.count()):
    command = stack.command(ndx)
```

The `command` will have the type of your specific `QUndoCommand` class (i.e. either `CommandA` or `CommandB`), so you can use `isinstance` to check which one it is.

Hence, you can make a `QWidget` (e.g. a `QtWidgets.QPushButton`) or `QAction` whose `triggered` signal is connected to a function (slot) that undoes the last `n` `CommandA` commands:

```py
def undo_last_n_CommandAs(n):
    for ndx in range(stack.count()):
        command = stack.command(ndx)
        if n > 0 and isinstance(command, 'CommandA'):
            command.undo()
            n -= 1
```